# HIbernate do not use sequence for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, sequence

I'm stuck in some problem: I need to use sequences in PostgreSQL for generating ids. But when I save new object in table, it says that id is null

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

I use these annotations:

```
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "fooGen", sequenceName = "FOO_SEQ",   allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "fooGen")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "numeric")
    private BigInteger id;
```

And this worked fo Oracle. I've watched a lot of questions, but most used GenerationType.AUTO or GenerationType.IDENTITY, and solution was to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE. But I'm already using it.

I got this exception when trying to save my entity with repository method

```
fooRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
```

My database is PostgreSQL 9.6.1.
I use

```
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Sequence exists, I checked it. And hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate would give me exception if it wouldn't be there.

Please, help me, where did I make a mistake?

I am using database schema:

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.postgresql.schema}</prop>
```

maybe, this cause some problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may sound stupid, but do you have this seq `FOO_SEQ` in your DB?

Comment: Yes, I have sequence in db schema that is used by my application

Comment: If you are still in the phase you can tweak in the db, I'd suggest you to use `serial` fields and leave postgres take care of the rest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This table has many-to-many relation, and table that connected two entities has its own id field. Hibernate had no mapped Java class for this table, and didn't set this id. And solution was to remove this field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type for id to `Long` like

```
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "fooGen", sequenceName = "FOO_SEQ",   allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "fooGen")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "numeric")
    private Long id;
```

Comment: To be sure - all annotations are imported from package 'javax.persistence', rigth?

Comment: Yeah, but I wrote some simple code that creates my entity. And it worked without any exceptions.
So, there must be mistake in some other places, thanks for help)